# How to pass EJS variable to data-src of LightGallery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ejs

I want to design Image Gallery using LightGallery in nodeJS. It works fine when I statically pass names of images (path) but Now I want to pass EJS variable which will contain name of all images in folder, but it is not working

This is code

```
      <% images.forEach(function(image){ %>
       <% var imgpath = '/'+ new String(image) %> 
         <div class=" col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
           <div  zoom="false" data-download-url="false" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Classic view </p>" data-src= <%= imgpath %> > //not Working Here tried Adding quotes still...
           <a href=""> 
           <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src= "<%= imgpath %>" > 
           //This works fine here
           </a>
         </div>
      </div>

 <% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer! It's a Bootstrap error, I used ```
Thats where the problem is!